# Vue/Sequelize/Axios: Delete Request: console of the browser shows a Bad Request, though the deletion is really done (?)

Tags: mysql, vue.js, axios, sequelize.js

I'm calling this function to request a deletion.

```
deleteMessage(a) {
            axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/api/messages/", {
                headers: { 
                     "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token") 
                },
                params: {
                    messageId: a,
                    
                }
                })
            .then((res)=> console.log(res))
            .catch(error => console.log("ligne 133 " + error))

        },
```

The controller below handles this function:

```
exports.deleteMessage = (req, res, next) => {
    Message.destroy({ where: { id: req.query.messageId }})
    .then( (res) => { res.status(200).json({ message: "Message supprimé !" }) })
    .catch( (error) => { res.status(400).json({ error })})
}
```

Result is:

```
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `Messages` WHERE `id` = '5'
```

In MySQL I see that the deletion has been done.

So, it works...

THOUGH, in the console of the browser I see:

[image]

How?

So My solution will be to call a function when the error occurs.... though it's not the best way.

Comment: Inspect what's going on in the backend side of the API: I suppose it is executing the delete request from your table correctly, but what kind of response are you returning to the client?

Comment: The controller is supposed to send a response code 200 and 400 if something went wrong. Is there a problem about these statuses ? Going to try changes here.

Comment: Seems like the catch block is being invoked. Is `Message.destroy` throwing any error?

Comment: I'll check and I'll come back on this (unfortunately not time for now...)